# Namespace is applied to child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input(excluding full file for brevity):

**input.xml**

```
<Request>
    <EFS>
        <child1>
            <!-- children -->
        </child1>
        <child2>

        </child2>
    <!-- more children etc-->
    </EFS>
</Request>
```

I want to remove the `<Request>` element, so `<EFS>` becomes the new root element, and then I want to add the namespace to it. My XSL is as follows(also shortened):

**my-stylesheet.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  version="2.0"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" copy-namespaces="no" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EFS">
   <xsl:element name="EFS" xmlns="'http://www.EFS-standards.org/standards/PC_Surety/EFS1.6.12/xml/Intake'">
       <xsl:call-template name="createEFScontent"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="createEFScontent">
        <xsl:element name="AuditTotal">
            <xsl:element name="TransmissionID" />
            <xsl:element name="MessageQuantity" />
            <xsl:element name="TotalAmt">0.00</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rest of stylesheet -->
```

So  `<Request>` is removed and `<EFS>` becomes the new root. After this I'm applying a namespace to `<EFS>` and the output looks as follows:

**output.xml**

```
<EFS xmlns="'http://www.EFS-standards.org/standards/PC_Surety/EFS1.6.12/xml/Intake'">
   <AuditTotal xmlns="">
      <TransmissionID/>
      <MessageQuantity/>
      <TotalAmt>0.00</com.LibertyMutual_TotalAmt>
   </AuditTotal>
   <child1 xmlns="">
      //children
   </child1>
   <child2 xmlns="">
       <!-- children -->
   </child2>
   <!-- rest of output -->
```

I'm not sure whats going wrong. I want the output to look as it does now without xmlns="" on child 1 and 2. Do I need to add another template to strip these out? Am I making a mistake in the templates listed?

I'm using SaxonHE 9.7.0-8, and this is called from within a Camel route in a transform step(if that makes any difference). Also worth noting, it only applies the blank namespace to child 1 and 2 elements. There are no other children of EFS, but the child elements of child1 and child2 do not have the xmlns=""

EDIT: Following Tim C's answer, I have replaced the Identity template with his and added the template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
```

This applies the namespace to EFS. The namespaces either appear blank on some elelements or with the full namespace value when I add a template like the following:

```
    <xsl:template match="EFS/child1/AddRq/Policy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:element name="RDDCd">
            <xsl:call-template name="getRDDCd" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

When this runs, Policy will be output with xmlns="" and RDDCd(along with an existing child element of Policy) will contain xmlns=

There are quite a  few of these templates in the xsl; Im trying to copy the existing content of the matched element, and add a new one, then return to the identity template( I think, I'm not great with xsl). Is there something I'm doing glaringly wrong? Most of my tempaltes are matchign to elements in the source, copying the contents over and adding a new child(covers around 70% of the templates in the stylesheet). As mentioned, I've been creating these templates in the fashion of the one above, with the rest being element removal:

```
<template match="MSDCd" />
```

Or changing the value of an element/child of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating new elements, such as `AuditTotal` then you will need to make sure these are created with the new namespace as well. You could do this..

```
<xsl:element name="AuditTotal" namespace="http://www.EFS-standards.org/standards/PC_Surety/EFS1.6.12/xml/Intake">
    <xsl:element name="TransmissionID" />
    <xsl:element name="MessageQuantity" />
    <xsl:element name="TotalAmt">0.00</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

... But it would be easier to define a default namespace in your XSLT to start with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="http://www.EFS-standards.org/standards/PC_Surety/EFS1.6.12/xml/Intake"
version="2.0">
```

Additionally, for the identity template, you are using `xsl:copy`, but these will copy the elements from the source document, which are in no namespace, and so they will have no namespace in the output too. Instead you need to create new elements in the required namespace too.

Indeed, you should not be using `xsl:copy` anywhere in your XSLT, if all elements in your XML are in no namespace, but you want all elements in your output XML to be in a namespace. You should replace `xsl:copy` with this..

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
```

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="http://www.EFS-standards.org/standards/PC_Surety/EFS1.6.12/xml/Intake"
version="2.0"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" copy-namespaces="no" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EFS">
   <xsl:element name="EFS">
       <xsl:call-template name="createEFScontent"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="createEFScontent">
    <xsl:element name="AuditTotal">
        <xsl:element name="TransmissionID" />
        <xsl:element name="MessageQuantity" />
        <xsl:element name="TotalAmt">0.00</xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So this sort of worked, I'll add more to the input/output xml, but essentially any other element that I'm matching in a template now either have xmlns="", or the full xmlns string

Comment: Actually I've narrowed down the conditions for when it adds the namespaces in. In some tempaltes, I'm matching a particular element, then I call <xsl:copy>, and do whatever needs done, e.g. <xsl:element>, followed by <xsl:apply-templates />. Once I do this, I either get the xmlns with the full namespace value, or blank one. Will update question

Comment: You should not be using `<xsl:copy>` in this case. If the element has no namespace in the source XML, it will be copied to the output XML with no namespace, resulting in `xmlns=''` being shown. You should use `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">` instead.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information on the intent of the stylesheet. I more or less want to match elements in the source, copy them and their contents,and for around 70% of cases add a new element, then, for lack of a better way to phrase it, return control to the identity template, . I've been using the format posted at the end of the question; from my understanding xsl copy would copy the elements contents but is this the wrong way to go about that kind of operation?

Comment: An element in no namespace is different to an element in a namespace, even if the actual name is the same. Therefore you need to create a new element, rather than copy the existing one, which is why I say about using `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use a standard identity template for this. You'll need templates to match each of your different cases and then copy the names/content without the namespaces. Something like this should work, although note that it may not give you the expected behavior for empty elements (`child2`) in your case.  This has templates for each node type you want to copy, and by default puts everything in your desired namespace (the `xmlns` in the root of the stylesheet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  version="2.0"
xmlns="http://www.EFS-standards.org/standards/PC_Surety/EFS1.6.12/xml/Intake"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="*">

        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()|processing-instruction()|comment()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EFS">
        <xsl:element name="EFS">
            <xsl:call-template name="createEFScontent"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="createEFScontent">
        <xsl:element name="AuditTotal">
            <xsl:element name="TransmissionID" />
            <xsl:element name="MessageQuantity" />
            <xsl:element name="TotalAmt">0.00</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is for a downstream system, and as far as I know the elements must come in without the namespace prefix. Its a strange requirement, but only the new root must have the xmlns section on it, the rest must remain as is

Comment: Edited the answer.